# How to stop menu links being disabled after saving nodes?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation, i18n-l10n

A localised Drupal 7 site I'm working on has a navigation menu along the top. Each node is provided with a menu link with a given weight. Nodes are translated into three (non-English) languages (the admin language is English). The nodes show on the menu correctly depending on the current language.

Whenever I edit a node (eg edit the title, body) and click Save, its links disappears from the menu.

The same thing happens if I edit a node but don't actually change anything, then click Save.

I can re-enable it by:

1. Edit the node again
2. Untick the menu link
3. Save
4. Edit the node yet again
5. Tick the menu link (re-filling the title/weight)
6. Save again

Or:

1. Go to admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu
2. All the other menu links are enabled, but the recently saved is not and has "(disabled)" after its name
3. Tick the box to re-enable
4. Save configuration

But how can I stop menu links from being disabled when a node is edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://drupal.org/node/1905268) in the latest version 1.8 of i18n  [Martins Bertins' patch](https://drupal.org/comment/7177560#comment-7177560) fixed this for me.

But its [parent bug](https://drupal.org/node/1693074) has been released in the latest dev version, and installing that fixed it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick fix:

1. Download version 1.7 of i18n.
2. Unzip it and find the folder named i18n_menu
3. Go to your site's modules directory (could be /sites/all/modules/)
       Find the folder i18n
4. Replace the subfolder i18n/i18n_menu with the version from version
   1.7 you downloaded in step 1

You can also check this bug report: http://drupal.org/node/1905268

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately if I do this, links don't disappear after edits, but instead I see *all* links from all three languages instead of just those for the current language. Any ideas?

Comment: I checked the bug, and its parent bug has been fixed and released in the latest dev version. Installing that fixed it. Thanks for the pointers!